# Strange MIPS AdES exception

Tags: exception, crash, mips, memory-address

I am giving very limited information, I know, but it is probably enough.

**System specs:** MIPS 64-bit processor with 8 cores running 4 virtual cpus each.

**OS:** Some proprietary Linux based on the 2.6.32.9 kernel

**Process:** a simple user-land process running 7 posix threads. This specific application is running on core 0, which does not have any cpu affinity by any process.

The crash is almost impossible to reproduce. There is no specific scenario. We know that, if we perform some minor activity with the application it might crash once a day.

The specific thread that's crashing wakes up every 5 milliseconds, reads information from one shared memory area and updates another. That's it.

There is not too much activity. The process is not working too hard.

Now: When I open the core and load a symbol-less image of the application, gdb points to instruction 100661e0. Instruction 100661e0 looks like this (viewing with an objdump view of the non-stripped image):

```
void class::foo(uint8_t factor)
{
    100661d8:   ffbf0018        sd      ra,24(sp)
    100661dc:   0080802d        move    s0,a0
    bar(factor, shared_memory_a->profiles[PROFILE_1]);
    100661e0:   0c019852        jal     10066148 <_ZN28class35barEhR30profile_t>
    100661e4:   64c673c8        daddiu  a2,a2,29640
    bar(factor, shared_memory_a->profiles[PROFILE_2]);
    100661e8:   de060010        ld      a2,16(s0)
```

The line that shows as the exception line is

```
100661e0:   0c019852        jal     10066148 <_ZN28class35barEhR30profile_t>
```

Note that 10066148 is a valid instruction.

The Bad register contains the following address, which is aligned, but does not look valid as far as the instruction address space is concerned: c0000003ddc5dd90

The cause register contains this value: 0000000000800014

I don't understand why the Bad registers shows the value it does, where the instruction specifically states a valid instruction. I am a little concerned about branch delay slot issues, but I shouldn't be concerned about those when I am running a userland application using simple C++.

I'd appreciate any thoughts.